# How to stop mangled output packets from using default route?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a router. It has a few interfaces. One of them is the VPN called vpn0, one is the default route to the physical interface, called out0 and an input interface in0.

Packets from in0 with destination port 993 are never to be placed on out0. I do this by marking the packets thus:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i in0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j MASK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i in0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

and to disable forwarding on out0 I do the following:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i in0 ! -o vpn0 --match-mark 100 -j DROP -m conntrack --ctstate NEW
```

The problem I am having is with output packets that are coming from host. To mangle packets out vpn0 I have these rules:

```
iptables -t mangle  -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --dport 993 --jump MARK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --dport 993 --jump CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --dport 993 --jump RETURN
```

Which works rather well. The only occurs when vpn0 isn't working. I tried adding the rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --dport 993 -o out0 --match mark  --mark 100  --jump DROP -m conntrack --ctstate NEW
```

But this drop packets that would got out the VPN. I checked this by changed the DROP to a LOG and the out interface is out0, not vpn0.

What gives?